# Defining my own JQuery function for multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I have defined a JQuery function that gets called by some element and adds an event listener to scroll.

It works great if only one element calls that function, but if multiple of them does, it is only working for the last one that called it. Let me explain it better adding some code:

My function:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    objectParallax: function (speed) {
      var elem = $(this);
      var defaultTop = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
      window.onscroll=function(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        elem.css('top',(defaultTop-(scrolled*speed))+'px');
      }
    }
});
```

It's quite simple, basically what it does is making some element scroll at a different speed.

I call the function this way:

```
$(function(){
     $('#floating-parallax-1').objectParallax('.5');
     //$('#floating-parallax-2').objectParallax('.5');
     //$('#floating-parallax-3').objectParallax('-.5');
     //$('#floating-parallax-4').objectParallax('-.5'); 
});
```

So, in this case(^), it works great for my `#floating-parallax-1` object. But if I uncomment the other ones my function only works for the last one of them. See:

```
$(function(){
     $('#floating-parallax-1').objectParallax('.5');
     $('#floating-parallax-2').objectParallax('.5');
     $('#floating-parallax-3').objectParallax('-.5');
     $('#floating-parallax-4').objectParallax('-.5'); 
});
```

Here(^) the function is only working for `#floating-parallax-4` item.

How can I make this function to be able to have multiple instances of it simultaneously?

*I'm sorry for my bad english, if something is not clear enough please ask me. Thanks for your help!*

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you overwrite  `window.onscroll` each time plugin function is called. Thus `window.onscroll` will only be valid for last element the plugin gets initialized for since it is a global window property

Try using `jQuery.on()` instead.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    objectParallax: function (speed) {
      var elem = $(this);
      var defaultTop = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
      $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        elem.css('top',(defaultTop-(scrolled*speed))+'px');
      });
    }
});
```

Think of it with this simple example

```
// first time plugin gets initialized
foo = function(){
   alert('One');
}
// next time it overwrites the previous `foo` instance with new one
foo = function(){
   alert('Two');
} 

foo()//alerts only "Two"
```

> Additional plugin comments:

If you want plugin to be able to be called on more than one element at a time always use `return this.each` inside plugin since `this` in plugin will contain the whole collection of elements that match selector(s). Or do `this.each` and just return `this` at the end. It is `return this` that lets you do method chaining

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  objectParallax: function(speed) {
    var $window = $(window);
    // loop over all elements in collection
    return this.each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      var defaultTop = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
      $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolled = $window.scrollTop();
        elem.css('top', (defaultTop - (scrolled * speed)) + 'px');
      });
    })
  }
});
```

Then you can combine selectors and the plugin will treat each element instance separately inside the `each` loop.

```
 $('#floating-parallax-1, #floating-parallax-2').objectParallax('.5');
```

Comment: works like a charm! and also thank you for the advice for making my function able to deal with multiple selector matches, I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem... lots of other patterns that can be built into plugins but you now have the basics down to be able to throw quick ones together ...and allow them to chain to other jQuery methods

Comment: If you don't mind, would you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513803/jquery-custom-plugin-function-validate-options Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        elem.css('top',(defaultTop-(scrolled*speed))+'px');
      }
```

this will not add new callback but replace previous one, so try to add new event instead replacing it,