# Jquery custom plugin function validate options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Let´s say I have defined a JQuery function as may be the following:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  objectParallax: function(speed) {
    var $window = $(window);
    return this.each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      var defaultTop = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
      $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolled = $window.scrollTop();
        elem.css('top', (defaultTop - (scrolled * speed)) + 'px');
      });
    })
  }
});
```

I want the parameter `speed` to be an option instead of a parameter(my real function is a bit more complex than this, and it has a few more parameters which I also want to become options). How can I do this? And how can I validate that `speed` is a number between -2 and 2, and throw an error in console if it´s not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you want to define options object and also pass in an object instead of `speed` variable and extend the defaults with user defined options

The basics will look like:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  objectParallax: function(options) {

    // plugin defaults
    var defaults = {
      speed: '.5', // expect values between -2 & 2
      /* other properties and default values */   
    };

    // in case no user options object provided make sure we pass object to settings extend
    options = options ? options : {};

    // create settings by extending defaults with user defined opts
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // ultra basic speed validation
    if (settings.speed < -2 || settings.speed > 2) {
      console.error('Speed not in limits');
      return;  // quit if not valid  
    }   

    var $window = $(window);
    return this.each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      var defaultTop = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
      $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolled = $window.scrollTop();
        // use settings properties instead of `speed` argument
        elem.css('top', (defaultTop - (scrolled * settings.speed)) + 'px');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now instead of passing string variable in pass in an options object that can contain any or all of the properties required by plugin. If you don't include a property/value then plugin will use the default

```
var opts = {speed: 1.5 };
$('#floating-parallax-1, #floating-parallax-2').objectParallax(opts);
```

Most of this along with some more advanced concepts is outlined in the [jQuery Learning Center/Plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

There are also lots of other resources on web regarding jQuery plugin patterns as well as boilerplate sites and seed projects